# Protractor: how to prevent chrome webdriver service from stopping session automatically

Tags: protractor

When my testcase is running, the session is automatically stopped after 10mins.

INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session fbd843ab66cb10a21d00b07eb4466970 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)

Is there any way to not stop automatically, or extend the time ? The conf.js file is as follows.  Thanks.

// File: conf.js

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

```
// set default time out for pending asynchronous tasks in Angular application 60 mins
allScriptsTimeout: 3600000,

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,

    // use colors in the command line report.
    showColors: true,

    // override jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL for asynchronous callback
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000
},

onPrepare: () =>{
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

    let origFn = browser.driver.controlFlow().execute;

    // set protractor wait time
    browser.driver.controlFlow().execute = function () {
        let args = arguments;

        // queue 100ms wait
        origFn.call(browser.driver.controlFlow(), () => {
            return protractor.promise.delayed(100);
        });

        return origFn.apply(browser.driver.controlFlow(), args);
    };
},

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    'version': 'ANY',
    'shardTestFiles': false,
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', 'disable-infobars'],
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false
            }
        }
    }
},

// command line params
params: {
    all: '',
},

// Specify the name of the specs files.
specs: ['./tests/link.js'],

// Run specified suites: protractor conf.js --suite portfolio
suites: {
    all: 'tests/*'
}
```

}

Comment: Can you attach your full config file

Comment: attach protractor config file.

Comment: Here is the config file.

Comment: I modified the original message to include the config file.